# Bootstrap, I can't reduce the line-height less than a certain amount

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a span text that should change to:

```
font-size: 13px;
line-height: 1.38;
```

Using Bootstrap I noted that the line-height doesn't have any effect. I can see changes only when I set the value more than 1.6 onwards...

I added !important, but this is not changing the big space I have between lines, which should be less as showed in the designer prototype.

Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: try by adding `display: inline-block' on span

Comment: solved in that way!! thanks Ismail!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is because the span element is an inline element that provides no changes when line height is applied on it. 
You should rather wrap up the text in p or paragraph tag to make the line height work effectively.